# Override Browser Back-Button behaviour - don´t cancel Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, request, fetch-api

I have already read that it´s not possible to override the Button itself.

I have a View with a button, and I have an "Are you sure" prompt when the User closes/leaves the page. The button starts a long running Request, which blocks the site (Client Requirement) until it is done.

This is what happens:

1. Button is clicked
2. Form is submitted
3. fetch() begins to get the generated data from the Server
4. fetch attaches "beforeunload" Event
5. When the Process is done on the Server, it posts everything back to the User

Everything of the above works. My problem now is: When the User clicks on back or closes the Tab while the Process is still running, the "Going back" Prompt appears, if the User clicks on "Cancel", **he stays on the Website, but the Requests stops as does the fetch()**. Which is completely against the reason why I have the prompt.

So, **how can I keep the Request and the Javascript fetch() running** after an User decided to stay on the Website?

I have checked to change to "unload" Event and "popstate", but they do not seem to be the Solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the *onbeforeunload* here's a less intrusive (to procedures) alternative, which may work for you and can stop a user dead in their tracks with an alert box...

```
document.onvisibilitychange=function(){

 if(document.visibilityState=='hidden'){ alert('Please wait until we have finished submitting your form thanks!'); }

};
```

It basically checks if the user tries to leave the tab/window.

Come to think of it, maybe use a `<dialog>` instead of an alert box.

**NB:** You’ll have to make it a **named function** so that you can then cancel the event after say… 10 seconds or whatever.

Oh wait... I’ve got another idea! :)

```
window.onmouseout=function(){

// fire up a dialog

};
```

Comment: Doesn´t work: "Blocked confirm('Please wait until we have finished submitting your form thanks!') during visibilitychange."... But it still cancels the Request and moves to the previous site.

Comment: I guess you can’t use alert boxes that stop javascript and have to use a modal/dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Use [sendBeacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) in this situation instead of fetch.